# YA Sci-fi post-apocalyptic book series from late 90s early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a book series I read in high school.  I remember purchasing it from Wal*Mart between 1999 and 2003.  There were approximately 10 books in the series and the covers were dark with color on the bindings.  The books were thin.

It was a post-apocalyptic series involving teens and there were no adults left on the planet.  The main character was female, but there were many other teens in her group.

I vaguely remember a character named Lilith who ended up being a bad guy in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be the series [Countdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(novel_series))?

[image]

According to the Wikipedia description:

> New Year's Day 1999 brings a strange solar flare, widescale power
>   outages, and the death of everyone on Earth over twenty years old,
>   leaving desperate teenagers to face **the awakened Demon called Lilith**.

and also

> As the new year dawns, a reported "massive solar flare" causes power
>   failures all over the globe and adults and children everywhere to melt
>   into piles of "black goo." **Only young adults are spared**, among them a
>   quartet of drunken high school kids in suburban Seattle, two teens
>   whose fake IDs have gained them entry to a New York City nightclub, a
>   cocky young doctor in a Texas hospital, a pair of tough-talking
>   inmates in a Pittsburgh jail, and Sarah and Joshua Levy who
>   desperately search the ancient scroll of their granduncle Elijah for
>   clues to the apocalyptic event.

They all seem to have been released in 1999, with the unusual gimmick of each being released one month before its titular period (the books are named after months).

Comment: I definitely think that's it.  Thank you!!